# Javascript to Select item from listbox by value number

Tags: javascript, select

I have a listbox on a page:

```
<select id="user_list" name="user_list" size="21" style="width:200px;">
  <option value=1>User 1</option>
  <option value=2>User 2</option>
  <option value=3>User 3</option>
  <option value=5>User 5</option>
  <option value=6>User 6</option>
</select>
```

And if I select a item I can get the current value by using the following code:

```
var el = document.getElementById("user_list");
var val = el[el.selectedIndex].value;
alert(val);
```

However, the problem I am having is that I want to be able to search the user_list (start from 1) for the next avaliable number (in my example above it will alert 4, as that is missing)

But I have tried using:

```
var el = document.getElementById("user_list");
var val = el[4].value;
alert(val);
```

but it doesn't work, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My guess is that var val = el[4].value; is wrong.. ?

Comment: First example is working http://jsfiddle.net/5R9h9/ Can you just tell us where you are getting 4?

Comment: I was trying to get the 4th item in the list (well 3rd item as it starts at 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works well.
http://jsfiddle.net/ubpn7/

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.. It wasn't working before but for some reason it's now working.